# Alternative for Tuple (setter)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Tuple<UInt32, String, String>> listValues = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<uint, string, string>>();

private Tuple<uint, string, string> selectedListValue;
```

I'm binding the collection to a ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListValues, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         DisplayMemberPath="Item1"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My problem is, that I get an exception, because the Tuple of the selected item has no setter. Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?

```
public Tuple<uint, string, string> SelectedListValue
{
    get { return selectedListValue; }
    set
    {
        selectedListValue= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedListValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest in this case to use a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public uint UintProp { get; set; }
    public string FirstString { get; set; }
    public string SecondString { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> listValues = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

It is more flexible, and it have set property.